# Strip comments in CSS using VIM

Tags: vim

I think vim can really do this. I just don't know my way arround search and replace using regex. Can anyone help me around this one.

**Update**
Thanks to Chris below for helping me around this one. Here is the map.

```
map <leader>rc :%s@\v/\*([^*]\|[\r\n]\|(\*+([^*/]\|[\r\n])))*\*+/@@g<cr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:%s@/\*\([^*]\|[\r\n]\|\(\*\+\([^*/]\|[\r\n]\)\)\)*\*\+/@@g` will get rid of all CSS comments (note that's using `@` rather than `/` as the delimiter to avoid escaping the `\`

You can also use `\v`, the "very magic" flag (read `:help \v`), and not need to make the `()|+` characters magic: `:%s@\v/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/@@g`.

(This answer is just extending jball's answer by putting in the Vim syntax for it.)

Comment: Thanks mate :D
Tested this one in vim using map <leader>test :%s@/\*\([^*]\|[\r\n]\|\(\*\+\([^*/]\|[\r\n]\)\)\)*\*\+/@@g<cr>

It didn't work. Or I'm missing something. :)

Comment: @ragingmon you've mixed the two. You've got to either use the first, which escapes all the things, or the second, which sets it to "very magic". Then, when using `map`, you've got to escape (if not using the `\v` variant, double escape) the `|` as `|` is used to separate commands (see `:help :bar`).

Comment: Thanks Chris. Thank you for making me learn these kind of things. Here is the working one >> map <leader>rc :%s@\v/\*([^*]\|[\r\n]\|(\*+([^*/]\|[\r\n])))*\*+/@@g<cr>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex (from [Stephen Ostermiller](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)) that should match C style (e.g., `/* ... */` and hence CSS) comments:

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

Note: this will probably need adaptation to VIM's specific flavor of regex.

Comment: Really simpler is:  `/\\*\\_.\{-}\\*/` where `/` is no pattern delimiter.